# How to ignore both the first and last row in named ranges when sorting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner and hope the following makes sense.

Here is a script that employs a custom menu to sort three sections in a sheet.

I now need to amend the script so that it ignores both the first and last row in each named range when sorting.

I believe the first row can be ignored by referencing row 2, but am not sure how to incorporate this into the script.

Is it possible to ignore the last row?

```
// Sort multiple sections

function onOpen(e) {
var menu = [{name: "Sections", functionName: "SortSections"}]
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Sort", menu);
}

function Sort() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(), rangeToSort = sheet.getRange("Section1");  
rangeToSort.sort([{column: 3, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(), rangeToSort = sheet.getRange("Section2");  
rangeToSort.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(), rangeToSort = sheet.getRange("Section3");  
rangeToSort.sort([{column: 3, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to build a new range to sort on from your named ranges. It takes a bit of logic, but should look something like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(), rangeToSort = sheet.getRange("Section1");
var trimmedRange = sheet.getRange(rangeToSort.getRow()+1,                              //skip first row,
                                  rangeToSort.getColumn(),                             //start column
                                  (rangeToSort.getLastRow() - rangeToSort.getRow())-1, //calculate range height, drop last row
                                  rangeToSort.getLastColumn()-rangeToSort.getColumn()  //calculate range width 
                                 );
trimmedRange.sort([{column: 3, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);
```

See docs for `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

And the various methods to determine columns/rows of a Range:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Thanks for your input @Cameron Roberts. Your solution works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the named ranges, get the part of the range you want to sort and sort ascending or descending:

```
function sort(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheets()[0].activate() //get Sheet1
  var allNamed=s.getNamedRanges() //get named ranges
  for(var i=0;i<allNamed.length;i++){ //for each named range
      var lr=ss.getRangeByName(allNamed[i].getName()).getLastRow() //get last row number of named range
      var col=ss.getRangeByName(allNamed[i].getName()).getColumn() //get column of named range
      var toSort=s.getRange(2,col,lr-2,1).getValues().sort() //get row 2 through next to last row. Sort
  if(allNamed[i].getName()=="Section3"){ //if named range is Section3, sort descending
      toSort.reverse()
  }
  s.getRange(2,col,lr-2,1).setValues(toSort) //return sorted part of nam   ed range.
  }}
```

This leaves the column header and the last row of each named range as it was.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to my query @Ed Nelson